# Dynamic tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have the custom `UIView` that I use as `tableheaderView` with the following constraints.

I set my `tableHeader` on the following way using RXSwift:

```
  viewModel.header.subscribe(onNext: { headerViewModel in
            let headerView = AttractionDetailHeaderView.grabFromNib()
            headerView.delegate = self
            headerView.setViewModel(viewModel: headerViewModel)
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
            self.sizeHeaderToFit()
            headerView.setNeedsLayout()
        }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

You see that I have `sizeHeaderToFit` method to resize my `headerView`:

```
func sizeHeaderToFit() {
    let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView!
    let footerView = tableView.tableFooterView!

    let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    var headerFrame = headerView.frame
    headerFrame.size.height = height
    headerView.frame = headerFrame

    var footerFrame = footerView.frame
    footerFrame.size.height = 40
    footerView.frame = footerFrame

    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
}
```

But my height of my `tableview` header is never correct.

Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677789/how-do-i-make-an-expandable-uitableview-header/35678459#35678459